# Predicting with Stateful LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, keras

Knowing the nature of my time series problem, I am using a stateful LSTM to forecast one step ahead.

My question is quite straightforward.

Do I need to explicitly save and pass the hidden cell in every prediction step in deployment, or Keras model already saves, updates and uses the states between predictions, and what I will do is simply predict as new data arrives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/) gives a good explanation

> **stateful**: Boolean (default False). If True, the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch.

In other words, when `stateful=True`, Keras saves the state between batches so that you don't have to.

This blog post has more details. http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/